# React Native build failing Could not HEAD /android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml'

Tags: android, react-native, maven, gradle

I'm trying to build my react native app which has been working for weeks, but now I'm getting the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.webkit:android-jsc:+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for org.webkit:android-jsc.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 11s
```

Supposedly there were incidents of jcenter going down, but they are fixed now, although I still get a 502 or 403 error when trying to access https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml.

I've tried replacing jcenter() with mavenCentral() with no luck. Any ideas how I can get this working?

Comment: bintray server is down for a little bit. Wait it to be repaired then build again later

Comment: Supposedly it is resolved - https://status.bintray.com/history. It's a day later and still getting 403 forbidden on this link

Comment: i had to switched offlineMode in gradle setting to build, glad to hear that jcenter is working again

Comment: Facing the same issue & status.binary.com says all fine? Any hints to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be jcenter(). The quickest workaround is to turn your wifi off before running the build command, then turn it on once it's up